# Where can I find a named report?

Tags: lightning, reporting, page-layout, unmanaged-package

I have the following XML from a layout file:

```
<layoutItems>
    <reportChartComponent>
        <cacheData>true</cacheData>
        <contextFilterableField>ACCOUNT_ID</contextFilterableField>
        <hideOnError>true</hideOnError>
        <includeContext>true</includeContext>
        <reportName>Opportunity_Amount_by_Stage_Sample</reportName>
        <showTitle>true</showTitle>
        <size>MEDIUM</size>
    </reportChartComponent>
</layoutItems>
```

Where can I find the referenced **Opportunity_Amount_by_Stage_Sample**?

The reports appear to be "Report Charts" in the "Page Layouts", though I don't know where these come from. I need to export it as part of a package but I can't find it listed anywhere. It's not already in the package, and on the "Add to Package" screen, it's not listed under "Report" or "Custom Report Type", and despite the layout being included, this doesn't seem to be included or listed as a dependency.

I've also looked under "Reports" from the "App Launcher" but I can't find it there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find your report in the UI, try running this SOQL query:

```
SELECT DeveloperName, FolderName FROM Report
```

This will return all of the org's reports with their parent folder.